# Number of queries in SEDE overflows

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, data-explorer

The total number of queries on SEDE (shown on the [query list page](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/queries?order_by=everything)) overflows sometimes, depending on the actual number:

[image]

I think it's still readable if the font size is reduced by a few points, or else a rounding scheme could be implemented as on other places in Stack Exchange; '1.4m queries' is accurate enough for me.

Tested on the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Not going to touch that but 300% as fontsize instead of 350% will work.

Comment: When I read the title, I expected to see a large negative count of questions.

Comment: @celtschk It's an HTML overflow, not an integer overflow ... I'm sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: Yaakov Ellis already fixed it and raised the [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/94)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed and deployed. I guess we are good now until we hit 10 million, right?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: 9,9 million queries ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: Tell us how the rate-limiting is set and we'll try it for you :-)